# Check if there is a next value in my django template for loop possible?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to check if there is a next value inside my for loop;
If so set a comma if not do nothing. Is there something like an {% ifnext %}?

Answer (score 1):

Quick research took me to the following solution. Assuming that we are in a forloop one could use:

```
{% if not forloop.last %},{% else %}{% endif %}
```